# Pagerank probability converging to zero?

Tags: python, math, pagerank

I'm attempting to code the pagerank algorithm from scratch, so far I have constructed the stochastic matrix `G` and now I am trying to find the limiting probability. The limiting probability is computed as follows:

```
- choose a random vector pi, such that each element is positive and sums to 1
- compute pi * G
- compute pi * G^2
- compute pi * G^3
- repeat until convergence
```

The result should be another vector with positive elements and sums to 1. When I do the calculation my result is converging to zero. Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np

# Define stochastic matrix (rows sum to 1), dimensions [6, 6]
G = np.array([[  8.29187396e-04,   4.98341625e-01,   8.29187396e-04,
      4.98341625e-01,   8.29187396e-04,   8.29187396e-04],
   [  3.32779623e-01,   5.53709856e-04,   3.32779623e-01,
      5.53709856e-04,   3.32779623e-01,   5.53709856e-04],
   [  1.66666667e-01,   1.66666667e-01,   1.66666667e-01,
      1.66666667e-01,   1.66666667e-01,   1.66666667e-01],
   [  4.98341625e-01,   4.98341625e-01,   8.29187396e-04,
      8.29187396e-04,   8.29187396e-04,   8.29187396e-04],
   [  1.66666667e-01,   1.66666667e-01,   1.66666667e-01,
      1.66666667e-01,   1.66666667e-01,   1.66666667e-01],
   [  1.65016502e-03,   1.65016502e-03,   1.65016502e-03,
      1.65016502e-03,   9.91749175e-01,   1.65016502e-03]])

# Compute probability vector by repeated multiplication
n_iter = 200 # Number of iterations
pi = np.random.random(size=6) # Random starting vector
pi /= sum(pi) # Normalise
evolution = [np.dot(pi, G**i) for i in range(1, n_iter + 1)] # Stores each step
```

The algorithm should converge to a result, and the sum of the result should be 1. However I get `evolution[-1].sum() = 0.043971902333195777`. Also, if I plot the result over each iteration it is clear that the result will eventually converge to zero:[image: Components of the probability vector]

Where am I going wrong? I'm confident that the transition matrix is correct, so I think the problem is in the calculation at the very end.
Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: For your `G` I get (via an eigenvalue calculation on its transpose using R) that the `pi` you are looking for is `[0.21591192 0.24269966 0.13528080 0.16206855 0.18938939 0.05464968]`. Why you don't get this I don't know. You are doing a fixed-point calculation and the zero-vector *is* a fixed point. Not sure why you are converging to that fixed point.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, `1` is an eigenvalue of the transpose of `G` and you want the corresponding eigenvector chosen so that it sums to 1. This can be found by Gaussian elimination, which can be done with `numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, what solved my issue was taking another look at the transition matrix. The rows of mine weren't summing to 1. Yours seem to sum correctly or are very close to and are probably within a floating point error.

But just make sure that that's the case and debug further from there.

Comment: If you already determined that your answer doesn't apply to his problem, then why answer in the first place?

Comment: Firstly I'm not sure his rows are in fact summing to 1. Secondly I was searching regarding this topic and didn't find this conclusion anywhere else so I left it so other people with a similar issue might find it (sorta the point of StackOverflow imho).